# WCF project output error

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF. Now working with a learning example. My environment is VS2008, .Net framework 3.5, Hosted in Windows sever 2003 R2.

The following code i have in a Service.svc file-

<% @ServiceHost Language=C# Debug="true" Service="MyWCFService" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" %>

But when i test it in browser, browser returns an error with the following lines-

The XML page cannot be displayed

A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource "http://localhost/WCFServiceDemo/Service.svc". Error on line 1 at column 2:

I could not find the error.

Any help is appreciable.

SKPaul

Answer (score 1):

go to IIS, open the node called Web Service Extension. Make sure that ASP.NET v2.0.5.0727 is set to Allowed. if it was set to Prohibited, Just click Allow button to enable ASP.NET.

if you still have same error try to do following

1.Open a command prompt and navigate to this dir
`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`

Run these commands in this order from command prompt:

`aspnet_regiis.exe –i`

2.Go to: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation

and then run:

`ServiceModelReg.exe -i`

3.Restart IIS

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between "%" and "@". In the example I just found in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx) there is no space.

Answer (score 0):

If you has installed Framework 2.0 and 4.0 verify the mapping

For sites with Framework 2.0 the map is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

For sites with Framework 4.0 the map is

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

To see the current map in your site [go to this URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252.aspx).

in the section:

> **To verify that the svc file type is mapped to be handled by aspnet_isapi.dll in IIS 5.1 or 6.0**